# Textbox not show datepicker with javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, datepicker, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress develop my website...Now i'm use Aspxtextbox with jquery to display datepicker. I don't use AspxDateEdit because i can't apply my css...Here is my code:

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
$("#<%= txtDate.ClientID  %>").datepicker(
{ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', minDate: 0 })
});
```

**ASPX**

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox Native="true" CssClass="span3" runat="server" ID="txtDate">
    <ValidationSettings ErrorDisplayMode="Text" ErrorFrameStyle-ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" ErrorTextPosition="Bottom" SetFocusOnError="true">
        <RequiredField IsRequired="True" ErrorText="The value is required" />
    </ValidationSettings>
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

When i view source code, input **id = ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_txtDate**..What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Do you have the jQuery UI CSS referenced in your markup?

Comment: @Karl yes i did, but nothing change...But in demo page, my code still work well

Comment: So without DevExpress it works fine, but with it, then it does not work?

Comment: @Karl yes mate...But i don't think that's cause...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the datepicker to work you need to reference both jQuery and THEN (note the order) -> jQuery UI.

So it will be something like this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/yourapp.js"></script>
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Also, not sure if the textbox ID is actually trimmed, so try to remove the spaces:

```
$("#<%=txtDate.ClientID %>")
```

Comment: @user2494232 Check my Edit, also make sure that the jquery references are in the correct order.

Comment: Thank you so so much...My code work well now...But i don't understand the spaces affect my code?

Comment: @user2494232 You're welcome :). And yes, the spaces might affect your code because you're searching for an ID that has a slightly different name actually :) " this" is different than "this".